# Find element that's on the middle of the visible screen (viewport), on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if there is a way I can determine if a div is in the center of the screen.

### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="box" id="box0">
  text
 </div>
 <div class="box" id="box1">
  text
 </div>

 .....

 <div class="box" id="box100">
  text
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to determine when a div will be in the center of the visible screen, considering that the page is scrollable? So basically, when the user is scrolling down the page, the div that's in the middle of the visible screen should be selected.

Thanks

Comment: Dare I ask...what have you tried?

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/123999/104380

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/487073/104380

Comment: My common 3 step process for all problems in coding
1) google it
2) chatgpt it
3) If no reliable solution found then ask others

Answer (score 12):

## [DEMO PAGE](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/rwygwq)

```
var findMiddleElement = (function(docElm){
    var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,
        // here i'm using pre-cached DIV elements, but you can use anything you want.
        // Cases where elements are generated dynamically are more CPU intense ofc.
        elements = $('div'); 

    return function(e){
        var middleElement;
        if( e && e.type == 'resize' )
            viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;

        elements.each(function(){
            var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            // if an element is more or less in the middle of the viewport
            if( pos > viewportHeight/2.5 && pos < viewportHeight/1.5 ){
                middleElement = this;
                return false; // stop iteration 
            }
        });

        console.log(middleElement);
    }
})(document.documentElement);

$(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);
```

> Another way (for modern browsers only) is to use the [intersection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Is it possible to add `onmouseup` and `onmousedown` events so it can also be swipe-able vertically on desktop?

Comment: @MalenaT - Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Could you please help me how to do it or update your codepen example? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *swipe-able vertically*

Comment: [Like this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/iOS-7-Style-jQuery-3D-Animated-Value-Selector-Drumjs/examples/).

Comment: Sorry but I currently don't have the time

Comment: Thanks anyway. I need it asap. Can you please maybe give some clues how to do it so I can try to implement it?

Comment: @MalenaT - I still don't understand what exactly you want. the picture did not explain it

Answer (score 6):

This is nice method: [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

You can get the element in the center as so:

```
 var elem = document.elementFromPoint($(window).width()/2, $(window).height()/2);

//if you want jquery element you can get it.
var jqueryElem = $(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

The height of the window and the scrollTop() of the window will give you the range of offsets that exist in the users view:

```
var minHeight = $(window).scrollTop()
var maxHeight = $(window).height()
var middleHeight = (maxHeight + minHeight) / 2;
```

You could try using a viewport selector such as:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport
This will give you all visible elements. A plugin isn't needed but will ease the selection

```
var visibleElements = $("div.box").filter(":in-viewport")
```

From this selection you can then look for the element closest to the middleHeight:

```
var $midElement;
var distance = null;
var currDistance = 0;
visibleElements.each(function(index, element) {
    currDistance = Math.abs(middleHeight - $midElement.offset().top);
    if ( distance == null || currDistance < distance ) {
        $midElement = $(element);
        distance = currDistance;
    }
});
```

Haven't tested this but it should be along the right track.