# Apply CSS transition when element comes into viewport

Tags: css, animation, transition, viewport

I'm trying to apply CSS transition effect when an element comes to viewport (i.e. when user scrolls to it), but not before.

I already know how to use CSS transitions, but how do I apply them only when the element comes to viewport?

What it the best way of doing this? If there's some library's to simplify the task, I would be glad to know.

Comment: Post and example of code you have made

Comment: Here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26466655/104380

Answer (score 16):

Give CSS3 Animate It a go, makes the whole process as simple as adding a few clases.

http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/

Then you can just add the classes like this to get started.

```
<div class='animatedParent'>
<h2 class='animated bounceInDown'>It Works!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Dead link, unfortunately.

Comment: @Brad new link: https://github.com/Jack-McCourt/css3-animate-it