# How to store the item currently scrolled to in the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a page that displays a list of 100 items. How would I be able to store the item that is being scrolled to in the URL, so that the user can control which item is scroll to in the URL?

```
www.site.com/inventory?scroll_position=67
```

Comment: No clue what you mean store...... store where?

Comment: did you mean using # link?

Comment: www.site.com/inventory#item-67 there is a discussion about how to find item in center of screen https://stackoverflow.com/q/11760898/15273968

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a tag at the text you wish to scroll to:

```
<a name="scroll_position=67"></a>
```

The url needs to read: `www.myawesomesite.com/inventory#67`

When the page loads run the following javascript:

```
function scrollTo(hash)
{
 location.hash='#'+hash;
}
```