# Find element that's on the middle of the visible screen (viewport) to target another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am aiming to achieve is something that looks [like this](https://www.loom.com/share/8e13822eca9f4ca2bb48e595246345d0). you can see it in action on [this URL](https://www.env0.com/), if you scroll a bit.
I was thinking at first to try using inViewport, and every time a heading or a paragraph is in viewport to show one image and hide the previous. but my problem is that the elements are in viewport in conjunction 
This is the initial code I was using:

```
      $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
      let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
      let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
      let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight; // <-- here
      return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
      };    
     $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($('.heading1 ').isInViewport()) {
     //  Use .blogcard instead of this
     $('.img1').addClass('show');  
     } else {
     //  Remove class
     $('.img1').removeClass('show');
     }  
    if ($('.heading2 ').isInViewport()) {
    //  Use .blogcard instead of this
    $('.img2').addClass('show');        
    } else {
    //  Remove class
    $('.img2').removeClass('show');
    }
    });
```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768795/get-the-visible-height-of-a-div-with-jquery/26831113#26831113) but have no idea on how can I use is to my benefits.
I have also stumbled upon [this solution](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/rwygwq), which looks even smarter, but the code adds the classes to the selector in viewport and not to a different element.
This is the code applied there:

```
ar getElementsInArea = (function(docElm){
var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;
return function(e, opts){
    var found = [], i;       
    if( e && e.type == 'resize' )
        viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;
    for( i = opts.elements.length; i--; ){
        var elm        = opts.elements[i],
            pos        = elm.getBoundingClientRect(),
            topPerc    = pos.top    / viewportHeight * 100,
            bottomPerc = pos.bottom / viewportHeight * 100,
            middle     = (topPerc + bottomPerc)/2,
            inViewport = middle > opts.zone[1] && 
                         middle < (100-opts.zone[1]);
        elm.classList.toggle(opts.markedClass, inViewport);
        if( inViewport )
            found.push(elm);
    }
};
})(document.documentElement);
////////////////////////////////////
// How to use:
window.addEventListener('scroll', f)
window.addEventListener('resize', f)
function f(e){
getElementsInArea(e, {
    elements    : document.querySelectorAll('div'), 
    markedClass : 'highlight--1',
    zone        : [20, 20] // percentage distance from top & bottom
});  
getElementsInArea(e, {
    elements    : document.querySelectorAll('div'), 
    markedClass : 'highlight--2',
    zone        : [40, 40] // percentage distance from top & bottom
});
}
```

Would love all the help I could get. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find element that's on the middle of the visible screen (viewport), on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760898/find-element-thats-on-the-middle-of-the-visible-screen-viewport-on-scroll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using the IntersectionObserver API

It should be quite simple by using the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to watch for your elements intersecting the viewport, or any other (Options `root`) ancestor.
To **detect an element reaches the viewport vertical center** can be done by passing the Option `rootMargin` where the *bottom* and *top* values are set at `-50%`, with an Option `threshold` set to `0` (*as soon as one pixel enters that intersecting area*)

```js
// Utility functions:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// App:

const ELS_pictures = ELS(".picture");

const switchPicture = (EL_entry) => {
  const EL_picTarg = EL(EL_entry.dataset.reveal);
  ELS_pictures.forEach(EL_pic => EL_pic.classList.toggle("is-active", EL_pic === EL_picTarg));
};

// In Viewport
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => entries.forEach(entry => entry.isIntersecting && switchPicture(entry.target));

// Assign observer to all Elements with data-reveal attribute (Articles)
ELS("[data-reveal]").forEach(el => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(inViewport, {
    // root: (by default is Document),
    rootMargin: "-50% 0px -50% 0px", // set the root intersecting area as a tiny line in the vertical center
    threshold: 0, // 0 = as soon as 1px intersects
  });
  observer.observe(el);
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif;
}

.stickers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Article Component */

.articles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.article {
  margin: 100px 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

.pictures {
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #444;
}

.picture {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.3s opacity, 0.5s transform;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.picture.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p style="height: 80vh;">Scroll down...</p>

<div class="stickers">
  <div class="articles">
    <div class="article" data-reveal="#picture_1">
      <h1>Many cats</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio laudantium perferendis eius iusto vitae eaque, eligendi ullam, rerum maiores, totam velit! Debitis repudiandae aliquam placeat, minus. Facere nihil aspernatur nam!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" data-reveal="#picture_2">
      <h1>Little cat</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur perferendis possimus asperiores deleniti voluptatum amet nostrum ratione odio, a perspiciatis suscipit ab nulla repellat laudantium praesentium adipisci! Nihil ex, quos!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" data-reveal="#picture_3">
      <h1>Snowcat</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur perferendis possimus asperiores deleniti voluptatum amet nostrum ratione odio, a perspiciatis suscipit ab nulla repellat laudantium praesentium adipisci! Nihil ex, quos!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur perferendis possimus asperiores deleniti voluptatum amet nostrum ratione odio, a perspiciatis suscipit ab nulla repellat laudantium praesentium adipisci! Nihil ex, quos!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur perferendis possimus asperiores deleniti voluptatum amet nostrum ratione odio, a perspiciatis suscipit ab nulla repellat laudantium praesentium adipisci! Nihil ex, quos!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur perferendis possimus asperiores deleniti voluptatum amet nostrum ratione odio, a perspiciatis suscipit ab nulla repellat laudantium praesentium adipisci! Nihil ex, quos!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" data-reveal="#picture_4">
      <h1>Cat</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut recusandae doloribus laboriosam, quasi aspernatur modi illum voluptate dicta alias optio, omnis qui deserunt. Quisquam, beatae dolores cum nostrum sint minima!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pictures">
    <img class="picture is-active" id="picture_1" src="https://placekitten.com/380/300" alt="Catz!">
    <img class="picture" id="picture_2" src="https://placekitten.com/460/400" alt="Catz!">
    <img class="picture" id="picture_3" src="https://placekitten.com/400/450" alt="Catz!">
    <img class="picture" id="picture_4" src="https://placekitten.com/500/450" alt="Catz!">
  </div>
</div>

<p style="height: 180vh;">Etc...</p>
```

- Use `data-*` Attribute on your articles Elements where the value should match the selector of the related picture.
- Toggle a class i.e: `.is-active` using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that will determine the *active* styles for the matching picture Element
- To make the *fixed* effect use `position: sticky` on your pictures  parent element.