# Vertical carousel on scroll react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, carousel

I want to have a section of the website which is fixed while to slide the carousel on scroll (vertically). Once you are at the last slide the scroll will let you continue on the page instead of changing the slide of the carousel. No idea on how to do this

row with a different background color which remain fixed while the user slides through the carousel slides by scrolling the page. once we arrive on the last slide the scroll will do the usual function on the page

example https://www.petitmoulinstudio.com/#comp-kmkqr752

Comment: Please, if you missed it before asking, take a [tour], read [ask] then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just need an idea of what i need to do to create the carousel on  https://www.petitmoulinstudio.com/#comp-kmkqr752

Comment: You should put your own research efforts into solving your problem, show what you have tried, and add a brief description of your efforts plus the actual code that you have written and the precise problem that you're facing.

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024027/383904 ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you it makes sense i think i know now what i have to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://symphonious-souffle-1d5ccb.netlify.app/

You set fixed left side bar then use observable api to determine when the last component is in view at which point you set the fixed side bar to normal so it is released